# Two unmanned aerial vehicles,6 km and 8 km above the ground

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> Two unmanned aerial vehicles, 6 km and 8 km above the ground, move
> in east and north directions after passing over a ground station.
> The distance between two unmanned aircraft should be no more than
> $2\sqrt{3}$ km in order to avoid interruption of direct data flow. In
> this case, how many km should the total distance of unmanned aircraft
> to the ground station be maximum without disconnecting the direct data
> flow?

I added my solution's picture. Options are

A) $6\sqrt6$ km

B) $6+6\sqrt2$ km

C) $14,7$ km

D) $15$ km

E) $18$ km

What is my mistake?  I would appreciate it if you help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s in a 3-dimensional space. The North isn’t that way. It’s into the surface of paper instead.

I suggest that you suppose one aircraft moved $x$ km, the other $y$ km.

You have $x^2+(8-6)^2+y^2=(2\sqrt{3})^2\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=8$

And you have to find the maximal value of the total distance asked in the question, which can be expressed as $\sqrt{6+x^2}+\sqrt{8+y^2}$.

So the original question can be turned into:

> Given $x^2+y^2=8$, find the maximal value of $\sqrt{6+x^2}+\sqrt{8+y^2}$.

Comment: oh, got it! thank you so much.

Comment: You’re welcome.